# Java - downloading and sending file

Tags: java, xml, github, file-upload, send

I want to make login system. It will download xml file from github and then send it back with the new information. The xml file will look liked this:

```
<user id="1">
        <username>usern&me</username>
        <password>passw0rd</password>
</user>
```

The program will read the file and store it in array list. Then it will add the new information and write it into xml file. Then I need it to upload/send to GitHub. The file will be same, because GitHub automatically overwrite files with same name. How can I send it and upload it to my repository? What is the fastest way of doing this?

**Edit**

I will be using GitHub Java API.

https://github.com/eclipse/egit-github/tree/master/org.eclipse.egit.github.core

This API will help me to authenticate my Github account and commit the file to the Github.

I will be appending to XML file immediately after it is downloaded and store all the usernames and id and password into temporary array list, that will be destroyed after login. This will make a “fake” database.

For this I really need to be this process really fast. Everything in with download in 1 second. So I need some quick algorithm that will quickly write to xml file.

And if you have some good way to do this, how can more secure the password( even if the respository will be private, obviously) by encoding it. The encoding should be also fast as it can be.

Comment: I would check the github api.

Comment: Any suggestions about the API and how can I commit file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

I found awesome gist from user Detelca.
It isn’t well ducomented, but I know now how it works.
The link to gist is there: https://gist.github.com/Detelca/2337731

Simple explanation:

I need to connect to GitHub authentication.

```
GitHubClient client = new GitHubClient();
client.setCredentials("username", "password");
```

Define respository

```
Repository repository =  repositoryService.getRepository("User", "repository");
```

And make commit:

```
Commit commit = new Commit();
commit.setMessage("commit at " + new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()).toLocaleString());
commit.setTree(newTree);
List<Commit> listOfCommits = new ArrayList<Commit>();
listOfCommits.add(new Commit().setSha(baseCommitSha));           listOfCommits.containsAll(base_commit.getParents());
commit.setParents(listOfCommits);
commit.setSha(base_commit.getSha());
Commit newCommit = dataService.createCommit(repository, commit);
```

There are more things to do, but the code is long and you can look at it on the gist.

Thanks for help!